# Force a user's browser to retrieve the latest image from a server

Tags: javascript, html, image, refresh

I need to make sure, via javascript or otherwise, that browsers are getting the latest version of images on my web pages. Currently the images are simple html `<img src="">` and I am using the html header to prevent caching: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">`. When testing this in Firefox, the images are being cached and even after refreshing despite the page not being cached. The new page sometimes gets the old image. I have not been changing the name of the images in order to retain the same links to the images.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of - [This Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4076634/1823389

Comment: The easiest way to fight with cash, to add link attribute to image href e.g: src="/imgs/imgNumber1.png?1211212"

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782918/preventing-images-being-cached-in-the-browser